# Can I convert datetime like 2020-11-19 14:50:18+09 to datetime without offset in php?

Tags: php, postgresql

use php and PostgreSQL.
In my php code, I write field with

```
    date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Seoul');
    $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', time());

    $sql =<<<EOF3
    INSERT INTO CUM_ASSEMBLY (NUM_LOT, COUNT_GOOD, DATE_FIRST, DATE_LAST, ID_OPERATION, ID_PRODUCT) 
    VALUES
    ('{$num_lot}', '{$count_good}', '{$date_work}', '{$date_work}', '{$id_operation_assembly}', '{$id_product}') 
    ON CONFLICT  (NUM_LOT, ID_PRODUCT) DO UPDATE SET 
    COUNT_GOOD = EXCLUDED.COUNT_GOOD + CUM_ASSEMBLY.COUNT_GOOD,
    DATE_FIRST = CASE WHEN CUM_ASSEMBLY.DATE_FIRST > TO_TIMESTAMP('{$date_work}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
        THEN TO_TIMESTAMP('{$date_work}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
        ELSE CUM_ASSEMBLY.DATE_FIRST
        END,
    DATE_LAST = CASE WHEN CUM_ASSEMBLY.DATE_LAST < TO_TIMESTAMP('{$date_work}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') 
        THEN TO_TIMESTAMP('{$date_work}', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
        ELSE CUM_ASSEMBLY.DATE_FIRST
        END;
    EOF3;

    $stm = $pdo->prepare($sql);
    $stm -> execute();

    $pdo->commit();
```

And I found that DATE_FIRST and DATE_LAST fields have offsets like `2020-11-19 14:50:18+09` when I read the field with `SELECT DATE_FIRST AS FROM_DATE, DATE_LAST AS TO_DATE FROM CUM_ASSEMBLY;`

I checked if $date is datetime what I want and found it was the datetime of without offset.
Changing datatype of PostgreSQL from timestamptz to timestamp  back and forth couldn't change the result.
Changing default time zone with `date_default_timezone_set('Asia/Seoul')` made change. Just for checking

Tried this. I have no idea where it is, so I can't link to it. I just put the code I found this site.

```
list($mydate, $mytime) = explode('+', $reports[$i][$j]);
                    // Calculate seconds from offset
                    //list($hours, $minutes) = explode(':', $offset);
                    $hours = $mytime;
                    $minutes = 0;
                    $seconds = $hours * 60 * 60 + $minutes * 60;
                    // Get timezone name from seconds
                    $tz = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $seconds, 1);
                    // Workaround for bug #44780
                    if($tz === false) $tz = timezone_name_from_abbr('', $seconds, 0);
                    // Set timezone
                    date_default_timezone_set($tz);
```

Tried this code. I also get this code from stackoverflow.

```
$datet = new DateTime($reports[$i][$j]);
                    $datet->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Seoul'));
                    echo '<td>'.$datet->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'</td>';
```

All of them didn't help me.

Comment: Can you share any of your attempts?

Comment: I edited my question. And remaking the tables is what I tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in SQL. I guess that the type of DATE_FIRST and DATE_LAST is `timestamp with time zone` and it does contain an offset.
You can chop the offset by casting `DATE_FIRST::timestamp` though this is not a good idea.
What you actually see is the textual presentation of DATE_FIRST and DATE_LAST using the default date-time format specification of your tool.

If you want to *present* the timestamp without the offset then use `to_char` and specify the format that you need. For example:

```sql
select 
  to_char(date_first, 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as from_date,
  to_char(date_last , 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as to_date
from cum_assembly;
```

You can find details on format strings in the [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html).

**Edit**
If you want to *convert* date_first or date_last to UTC then use `at time zone 'utc'` like this:

```sql
select 
  to_char(date_first at time zone 'utc', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ssZ') as from_date,
  to_char(date_last at time zone 'utc', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ssZ') as to_date
from cum_assembly;
```

**Edit**
Please be careful when removing offsets. You live in a different timezone than I do. If you create a document in your app with offsets chopped and send it to me then it will be very very wrong. See the `Z` in my second example format.

Comment: The code you offered fixed it except for 1) `select 
  to_char(date_first at time zone 'Asia/Seoul', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ssZ') as from_date,
  to_char(date_last at time zone 'Asia/Seoul', 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ssZ') as to_date
from cum_assembly;` 2) I add this code `$datet = new DateTime($reports[$i][$j]);
                        $datet->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Asia/Seoul'));
                        echo '<td>'.$datet->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'</td>';`.  Without changing timezone to Asia/Seoul and inserting 2), I couldn't get what I wanted.Thanks.  cf. $reports has datetime.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. See comments for explanation. This basically takes your dates and converts them to UTC to 'normalize' the datetimes.

```
<?php

$date = '2020-11-19 14:50:18';
$dateWithOffset = '2020-11-19 14:50:18+09';

// Make DateTime objects out of the date strings.
$dateTime = new DateTime($date);
$dateTimeWithOffset = new DateTime($dateWithOffset);

// This demonstrates the offset from UTC given the implied and explicit timezone offsets
var_dump($dateTime->getTimeZone()->getOffset($dateTime)); // int(3600): 3600 seconds from UTC (1 hour) on this server.
var_dump($dateTimeWithOffset->getTimeZone()->getOffset($dateTime)); // int(32400): 9 * 3600

// Convert both dates to UTC
$dateTime->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
$dateTimeWithOffset->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));

var_dump($dateTime->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e')); // string(23) "2020-11-19 13:50:18 UTC"
var_dump($dateTimeWithOffset->format('Y-m-d H:i:s e')); // string(23) "2020-11-19 05:50:18 UTC"
```

Comment: when I run the above code you you offered on my machine, I got the result, `int(32400) int(32400) string(23) "2020-11-19 05:50:18 UTC" string(23) "2020-11-19 05:50:18 UTC"`. I thought the results are differ from each other.

Comment: Then you are in the +0900 time zone ;). When I said "on this server", I meant "in the timezone that is configured on the server I'm testing this on". I should have been more precise.